# jQuery Plugin Initialise function not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

for some reason the initialise function isn't being called when I call my jQuery plugin, this seems to work as expected on another plugin I have created.

Plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.youtubeVids = function( options ) {
        var settings = $.extend({
      num: 1,
      id: 'UCeNOYP-TQK-3P3JZerCjheQ',
      elm: null
    }, options );

        function initialize() {
            console.log('dsad');
      $.ajax({
            url: "channel-videos.php",
            data: { num: settings.num, id: settings.id },
            success: function(data) {
                if (settings.elm !== null) {
                    console.log("test");
                } else {
                    console.log("uh oh");
                }
            },
            dataType: "json"
        });
        }
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Call to the plugin:

```
<script src="/js-src/youtube-min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#vid1").youtubeVids({
  num: 3,
  elm: [ "#vid1", "#vid2", "#vid2" ]
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `initialize` function inside your `youtubeVids` function is never getting called, so basically nothing happens there (besides creating the `settings` variable and the `initialize` function.

You should call the `initialize` function inside:

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.youtubeVids = function( options ) {
    var settings = $.extend({
      num: 1,
      id: 'UCeNOYP-TQK-3P3JZerCjheQ',
      elm: null
    }, options );

    function initialize() {
      console.log('dsad');
      $.ajax({
        url: "channel-videos.php",
        data: { num: settings.num, id: settings.id },
        success: function(data) {
          if (settings.elm !== null) {
            console.log("test");
          } else {
            console.log("uh oh");
          }
        },
        dataType: "json"
      });
    }
    initialize();
  };
}(jQuery));

$("#vid1").youtubeVids({
  num: 3,
  elm: [ "#vid1", "#vid2", "#vid2" ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vid1"></div>
```

Comment: See I thought this but looked in my other plugin and I never call the function in there but it works, at least I cant find the initialisation

Comment: There are several ways to do so. Which plugin are you referring to?